# No Error on UPDATE QUERY yet the query doesn't executes

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an Update query, which i been trying to use to update the password of user using his email iD and this category of table name.

Unfortunately the query isn't giving any error when runned but doesn't executing either.

the query goes as:

```
<?php include('index.php'); ?>
<?php include('db.php'); ?>

<?php



$email = $_POST['email'];
$who = $_POST['who'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');


$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "UPDATE $who SET password = '$password'
WHERE email = '$email'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Password Updated Successfully. Please LogIn")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="index.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I even checked each variable individually that is it passing values or not. like the $who variable, email and password variables, they are passing values. but the query isn't updating the table cell.

Form for the same:

```
<?php 
    $email = $_GET["id"];
    $who = $_GET["id2"];
?>

        <!-- Banner Section -->
        <section id="banner" class="banner-slider">
            <div class="banner-img-slider">
                <div>
                    <div class="banner-thumb"><img src="assets/images/banner-img/team-banner.jpg" alt="" class="hide" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="blue-overlay"></div>
            <div class="banner-text-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="banner-text">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <form action="passsetinput.php" method="post">
                                <h2 style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:lightgreen; font-size:35px;"><strong>Set Password</strong></h2><br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" disabled style="width:250px;height:35px;padding-left:20px;border-radius:15px;" /><br><br>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Type Password Here..." style="width:250px;padding-left:20px;border-radius:15px;height:35px;" /><br><br>
                                <input type="hidden" name="who" value="<?php echo $who; ?>" />
                                <button class="button"><strong>Confirm Password</strong></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Content Start -->
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: This is so massively open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: is `$who` the name of a table in your database?

Comment: Yes dude . it is the name of a table @Mawg

Comment: It is almost certain that your where clause is not being matched. Try running the command in the MySql shell and see how many rows it says are affected.

Comment: echo $sql;  and run your query in phpmyadmin , you will easily resolve yourself

Comment: no error via the query, ok. BUT what about on the php side? you're not checking for errors there. Where is the form for this?

Comment: I sure hope this isn't going live.

Comment: query($sql) returns true even if there were no updates performed in your database.

Comment: Updated the form @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Please remove that hidden "who" input-tag. Better write the table-name directly in your sql-statement ... and by the way, have look at: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @Flocke I already tried directly including the table name into the query . yet it gave the same problem. However this is how i needed the query to be executed. so i can't

Comment: Is it somehow possible that your db doesn't allow update-queries without an id/primary-key in the where-part?

Comment: Plain Text Password.... How quaint!

Comment: @Flocke is it somehow possible that if db doesn't allow update-queries, it won't produce an error?

Comment: @Flocke Floke was right, some how the query executes when i introduce id of the column at WHERE clause. Flauke, please add the same as answer, however the rest couldn't get it. and upvote my question man, it was worth it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments (and approved by Harish K), sometimes datebases doesn't allow Update-QUERIES without an "id/primaryKey-part" in the WHERE-clause.

Simple solution: Modify your query like "UDATE ... WHERE ... AND id > 0". (I asume there exists a primary key called id which is of numeric type).